# iOS PhoneGap custom plugin packaging and buildscript

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have an iOS phonegap project having custom plugins. To generate an automated build script, I need to package the custom plugins into a library/ios framework and then use the generated library to create a phonegap ios build using the build script.

My Questions:

1. How can I successfully package the custom plugins
2. Any help with build script is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.